# Charging "Gel" batteries while on load

Tags: battery-charging

I have 300 amps 12V Gel deep cycle batteries bluged into suoer 50A smart 4 phase charger and a PC that works on a DC power supply takes around 5-30 A (15 amps most if not all the time).

Now I want to know if this is a good setup because during bulk charge phase the charger will push very high current 50A when the batteries are discharged by 30% and this may damage the batteries? if the PC was turned off. From what I know is that the charging current should not exceed 12.5% of total batteries capacities which is 36 of 300 Amps.

The thing is that I have a smart charger which changes the current and the voltages depending on battery state of charge, but having a load applied on it constantly may make it apply the wrong amount of current and voltages extending the bulk charge period and costant voltage phase and never enter the float charge phase so that does not look good to me, is it?

Comment: Does your charger specify that it can be used as a power supply or does it have a time-limited Bulk/absorption phase? Is it perhaps possible to put it into Float mode permanently? Your batteries will be damaged if you keep them at bulk/absorption voltage (above 14V) permanently so it all depends on how smart your charger is.

Comment: Is the charger measuring the battery current or the charger current (battery + load).  If the latter it will not be able to use the information.

Comment: I don't know if I can use it as a power supply. I am not even satisfied with it, but I couldn't find better one. It is suoer MA-1250A and yes the last phase is overcharging my batteries at constant 14.4V in cold 5-10 degree room. For longer period some water appear at the top so I unplug it after a while because it does not stop charging. I have a meter on the load and the charger meter. Both of them measure the current.

Comment: Be aware of the difference between Ampere-Hour (abbreviated to Ah) that is used for battery capacity and current that is measured in Amps. Your batteries are presumably 300Ah. Also, you don't say whether the batteries are in parallel or series . If they are in parallel 50A would only be 50/36A each which is very small in relation to their capacity.

Comment: The total capacity is 300 Ah as I noted properly and the charger can do 50A max as advertised. according to it's own amp metter it can do more than 55A max. However how batteries are combined is not the matter at all. (They are 12V 300Ah combined as noted)